# Circuit Breaker Finder always beeps on certain breakers

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

When looking for a particular circuit today, I found a couple breakers that just always beep, and at a different frequency (faster) than the Sperry transmitter does.

What would cause the circuit to broadcast a signal the receiver would interpret as the transmitter pulse?

Comment: Are the culprit breakers GFCIs or AFCIs by any chance?

Comment: Yes, they are! I saw that in common but wasn't able to find the answer on Google search results.

Comment: Are they GFCIs or are they AFCIs, and what make/model are they?

Comment: There's a pencil-written note next to a pair of breakers, linked by a switch yolk, and the bottom is pencil-labeled GFI. It also is labeled in a big bracket "sub panel", but nothing on the sub panel is beeping. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6g38htc532fvbd/GFI%20close%20up.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Or do you mean the outlets? I know there are several, including a hot tub.

Comment: I mean the breaker itself -- so far, I can't tell for sure if it's a GFCI or a regular breaker.

Comment: The photo is linked above. I don't know how else to ID the type

Comment: Can you give me a zoomed-out photo of the same breaker as in the photo above?

Comment: Sure, but its unlabeled and _doesn't_ beep. https://www.dropbox.com/s/etpkgtztocnzq2z/Pair%20of%20breakers%20stackexchange.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah, the photo isn't one of the culprits -- can you get me a photo of one of the culprit breakers?

Comment: Hopefully this gives some insight. Warning: obnoxious beeping. Turn your volume down. https://www.dropbox.com/s/etpkgtztocnzq2z/Pair%20of%20breakers%20stackexchange.png?dl=0

Comment: That sure isn't a GFCI breaker...so that theory's a bust.  Does the receiver still trip if the load hot is disconnected from the culprit breaker?

Comment: Some cheap LED lights can cause AFCIs to trip because it is putting off a lot of noise, the same kind of noise Circuit finders pick up on.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'll post pics of the sub ASAP

Comment: Breaker is to old and crusty looking to be an AFCI.  AFCI might use some high frequecy voodoo to do its stuff.  No user interface of a GFCI.  GFCI should operate entirely passively though.  Do you have any home automation stuff?  x-10, insteon, upb?  or any ethernet-over-powerline adapters?

Comment: I do have Ethernet over power line adapters!